# How to set MediaPlayer always active even if I change Activity?

Tags: java, android

I have an application that has multiple activities and I've set a MediaPlayer for each of them with the same jingle.
I was asking myself, there's a way to keep the music in the first MediaPlayer of the first Activity going on for all the time while the application is running even if it switches activities?

Comment: using a music service for play music on background if the app in back ground

Comment: Just make Mediaplayer static   Example:     public static MediaPlayer mPlayer;

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-building-an-android-audio-player-app/ refer this link..

Comment: You can add your Music player initialization and play music code on your parent activity or in the activity which extends Application class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use foreground service with notification, it runs in background which we can play media player. Here is the example
[ForeGround Service start and stop](https://github.com/DimaKoz/Android-Foreground-Service-Example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/foreground/service/SoundService.java)